# Is this how you implement a fixed time step gameloop in C++?

Tags: c++, sdl-2

I would like to know if I am implementing a fixed timestep gameloop in the right way so I can achieve framerate independent movement in my program.

```
    ...

    double start = 0, end = 0;

    double deltaTime = 0.0;
    double milliSecs = (1000.0 / TARGET_FPS) / 1000.0; //60 FPS

    while (!quit) {

        start = SDL_GetTicks() / 1000.0;
        deltaTime += (double)(start - end) / milliSecs;
        end = start;

        //Update/Draw Stuff
        while (deltaTime >= 1.0) {

            //Update Stuff

            deltaTime -= 1.0;

        }

        SDL_SetRenderDrawBlendMode(Renderer, SDL_BLENDMODE_BLEND);
        SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(Renderer, 0, 0, 0, 255);
        SDL_RenderClear(Renderer);

        Tile::drawTileMap(Renderer);
        Object::drawObjectArray(Renderer);

        SDL_RenderPresent(Renderer);

    }

    ...
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This question is off-topic on stack overflow, I guess it'd be better suited for the [code review stack exchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Mostly right.  Your first frame will have a big time step (since `end` is initially 0), and as you're using doubles you'll lose fractions of an inteval every time thru the loop (consider what happens when deltaTime == 0.9).

Comment: (To 1201ProgramAlarm) So I should change the doubles to floats then and initialize `end` as 'SDL_GetTicks() / 1000.0f'? Any other advice (if avaliable) would be greatly appreciated.